# From where can I download the database created by Hsu et al for MORFs?

Tags: database

I am working on an independent research project for which I require access to the MORF database created by Hsu et al. From where can I download the database of MORFs of IDPs and their binding partners that was created by Hsu et al.?

I would appreciate a link to that page. I have searched a lot of keywords on Google but I could not come up with it. I might have, but I'm not too certain of it. I have already wasted 3 days searching for it.

Comment: In the future, it would be really helpful if you at least included a link to the paper by "Hsu et al." We can't read your mind. Secondly, the contact information for the corresponding author is included in the paper for a reason. If a *careful* reading of the paper and all referenced supplemental material doesn't answer your question, then contact the author directly. Most scientists I know are very happy to talk about their research and answer any non-trivial questions you may have.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about biology.

Comment: @MattDMo I got access to the database about a few hours after asking this question but I forgot to come and close this question. As for the question details, yes I completely agree with you. I made quite a few errors due to haste in typing the question. I'll make sure I do not do that again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're looking for the dataset that was used to train MorfPred from this paper? http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22689782

There's a link to it on this page: http://biomine-ws.ece.ualberta.ca/MoRFpred/index.html

If you're referring to another paper, it is likely they used the same data set. The best way to find the supplementary data, is to read the paper thoroughly - this is a better approach than a Google search! Keep in mind though, that sometimes the data set is not publicly available and you must e-mail the researcher in question to request it.